# Rails view hash in view from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, hash

I have such controller action:

```
@constr_num.each do |o|
      as_oem = get_from_as_oem(o.ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER)
      if as_oem.present?
        oem_art << as_oem
      end
    end    
    @oem_art = oem_art.to_a.uniq
```

get_from_as_oem looks like this:

```
def get_from_as_oem(oem)  

    require 'mechanize'
   *************************
    html = page.body

    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
    doc.encoding = 'utf-8'

    rows = doc.search('//table[@id = "MainContent_GridView1"]//tr')
      @details = rows.collect do |row|
          detail = {}
          [
            [:car, 'td[1]/text()'],
            [:article, 'td[2]/text()'],
            [:group, 'td[3]/text()'],
            [:price, 'td[4]/text()'],
          ].each do |name, xpath|
            detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
          end
          detail
      end
    @details  
  end
```

if in view i write: =@oem_art i get

```
[[{:car=>"", :article=>"", :group=>"", :price=>""}, {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"1C0959799B 001", :group=>"STEUERG.", :price=>"274,22"}, {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"1C0959799B 003", :group=>"STEUERG.", :price=>"274,22"}, {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"1C0959799B 00E", :group=>"STEUERG.", :price=>"274,22"}, {:car=>"Volkswagen", :article=>"1C0959799B 00F", :group=>"STEUERG.", :price=>"274,22"}, {:car=>"Volkswagen", 
etc...
```

so how could i view it normal, like .each |c|  c.car etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @oem_art.each_pair do |oem_key, oem_value| %>
  <%= oem_key %> => <%= oem_value %></br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: undefined method `each_pair' for #<Array:0xa7a1ca0>   so it think it is array O_o

Comment: Yes, it's an array, of an array, of a hash.  Use each, and each_pair to unravel it.  Details left for the reader.

Comment: If you don't know how to navigate a ruby array of array of hash, then you need to spend more time learning ruby and rails to use this forum.

Comment: if i don't know this what are you saing, it's doesn't mean i don't know this... but how to use my brain on this concret thing i don't know...

Comment: Marlin... I think also you don't know everything on this world on 100%... People must help people, but not give advise like "you are s*cker"

Comment: I'm willing to give you help if you are stuck on not knowing an API, but accessing arrays and hashes are just basics in ruby and programming in general.

Comment: i can acces array, i can access hash... but access of array of arrays and hash is something( do you mean iterate via array, than array, and then hash?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the terminal or the browser for that. You can use `puts myhash.inspect` to print your "dumped" hash to the terminal resp. logfile.

Or you do something like this in your controller: `render text: myhash.inspect`

If you prefer solution one you can also enhance this experience with `ap` which is the gem awesome_print which provides prettier and colorized output in your console. On top of that you can give `pry` a try. With that you can set breakpoints and then start an interactive console right in that place.

Awesome print: https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print
Pry: https://github.com/pry/pry

Also: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html